# SSRS Drill through GO To URL Target=_Top

Tags: reporting-services

GO To URL is used for SSRS Drill through and it is adding target=_top automatically which makes url to open in new window. My requirement is to open the url in same window (target=_self). I am thinking target=_top is added in server level or in some configuration level.Can you please help to identify the spot on where the change the target attribute which is added automatically.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. Added the below in the end of the given open url

&rc:LinkTarget=_self&rc:Parameters=false"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the querystring is not an option for me because I need the link to communicate with a parent frame and open another framed "virtual tab".  The following works for me with SSRS 2019.

Modify

\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx

And change the RS tag from:

`<RS:ReportViewerHost ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server"/>`

to

`<RS:ReportViewerHost ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" HyperlinkTarget ="_self"/>`